# React: Sibling component communication issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am new to React and wrote a small app that is not working correctly. I am trying to have my `Checkbox.js` component communicate to my `SubmitButton.js` component whether or not it is checked so that the submit button will only be enabled if the user checks the box.

I tried using props as you can see in the code below but I am probably doing this horribly wrong. Can anyone help me learn the correct way to do this? Not sure if it matters, but I am using the Material-UI library. Thanks.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar'
import Form from './Components/InfoForm'
import SubmitButton from './Components/SubmitButton';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Checkbox from './Components/Checkbox';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checked: false,
});

const handleChange = name => event => {
  setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
};

  return (
   <div>
     <Container maxWidth="md">
     <NavBar />
     <Form />
     <br />
     <Checkbox onChange={handleChange('checked')} checked={state.checked} /> 
     <SubmitButton isEnabled={state.checked} /> 
     </Container>     
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

function Checkboxes() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        name = 'checkbox'
        value="checked"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox', }}
      /> By checking this box you agree to all terms and conditions specified above.
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

**SubmitButton.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {  margin: theme.spacing(1), },
  input: { display: 'none', },
}));

export default function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  if (props.isEnabled === 'true') {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  } else 
  {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled = 'true'>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1.

- `props.isEnabled` is boolean, not string.
- Else statement is redundant.
- `disabled='true'` is not string, its boolean.
- `isEnabled` is redundant, as `disabled` is already supported by `@material-ui/core/Button` which easily can be reused

```
    export default function ContainedButtons(props) {
      const classes = useStyles();
      return (
        <div>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled={!props.isEnabled}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

2 - Checkbox not using actual `value` and `onChange` handler from props

```
function Checkboxes(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        name='checkbox'
        value={props.checked}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox', }}
      /> By checking this box you agree to all terms and conditions specified above.
    </div>
  );
}
```

3 - You have terrible naming for Checkbox, your component name clashes with `@material-ui/core/Checkbox`

Comment: Hi Medet, can you please provide a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

1.You did not use props normally

- You passed props to Checkbox ( It was from Checkboxes component )

```
return (
   <div>
     <Container maxWidth="md">
     <NavBar />
     <Form />
     <br />
     <Checkbox onChange={handleChange('checked')} checked={state.checked} /> 
//...
```

- But in Checkbox.js, you didn't use this props. Please change like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

function Checkboxes(props) {
  const {onChange, checked} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        name = 'checkbox'
        value={checked}
        onChange={onChange} 
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox', }}
      /> By checking this box you agree to all terms and conditions specified above.
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

- And you already used name property in Checkbox, so you can pass name dynamically.
- event.target.name is 'checkbox'. So state will be stored at state.checkbox

```
//...

const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkbox: false,
});

const handleChange = event => {
  setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};

//...

<Checkbox onChange={handleChange} checked={state.checkbox} />

//...
```

2.SubmitButton.js is wrong

- You passed isEnabled props with boolean type. You should compared this props like this

```
if(props.isEnabled)
```

- Disabled propery in Button also need boolean type.
- And it is unnecessary to split jsx code.

```
return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled={!props.isEnabled}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Hi @bkm412 I made the code changes you suggested but the submit button still does not enable when I check the checkbox. I posted an image of the form above.

Comment: change state,checked -> state.checkbox and initialState also should be {checkbox : false}. I will edit code

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this and let you know how it goes. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was that I had to add the following after making the changes suggested by bkm412. I added the `name` property to the Checkbox element and `state.checkbox` to the SubmitButton element

```
<Checkbox name="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} checked={state.checkbox} />
<SubmitButton isEnabled={state.checkbox} />
```